# Argument of type boolean is not assignableto paramter of type 'string' in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new to typescript and need some help with the following functions.

What I am trying to achieve is that:

I am sending the token to my testFunc. After decoding the token, I am trying to access the property `'isUser'` which basically returns a string `'isUser':'true'` or `'isUser':'false'`. Now, I am trying to set a boolean value (`true or false`) to `isResult` based on that `isUser` value.

But, when I am trying to assign this value to local storage key I am getting error like:
argument of type 'Boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Here is the full functions:

```
export const testFunc = (token: string) => {
  const parseValue = (s: string) => s.toLowerCase() === 'true';
  const jwtDecoded = jwtDecode<JwtPayload>(token);

  const isResult = jwtDecoded.isUser ? parseValue(jwtDecoded.isUser) : false;

  localStorage.setItem('local-storage-key', isResult);
};
```

Assigning `isResult` to the `'local-storage-key'` through the error:

```
localStorage.setItem('local-storage-key', isResult);
```

And here is the sandbox link to highlight the error:
https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-johnson-82g542?file=/src/index.tsx

Any help with this would highly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: `isResult` is a boolean. `localStorage.setItem` takes a string. What about this isn't clear? Just convert the boolean to a string `localStorage.setItem('local-storage-key', String(isResult));`

Comment: is't that will return the local storage value as string: local-storage-key: 'false'? What I am trying to achieve is that: local-storage-key: false.

Comment: You can't do that, localStorage can *only* store strings and you have to parse them back into data on retrieval. It sucks, but that's the way it is.

Comment: But, I think we can also store boolean value to local storage? this is probably something related to the types?

Comment: No, **again**, localStorage can **only store strings**. Try it in plain JS in your browser console: `localStorage.setItem('foo', true)` followed by `localStorage.getItem('foo')` will give you back the *string* "true", and you can see it has nothing to do with types. Not relying on that sort of implicit type coercion is a big part of why Typescript exists, so the types are written to remind you that the API sucks and doesn't do what you think it does. It's a pretty common source of bugs, people try to store `{}` in localStorage and then wonder why they get back `'[object Object]'`

Comment: See the second dupe link I just added at the top of your question.

Comment: Hum really interesting. The link you posted, it actually return string based on boolean. But, my point is the opposite one. Return boolean based on the string value.I didn't notice this error before I converted that helper into typescript. In pure JS, I didn't even notice that.

Comment: Everything you put in localStorage is implicity converted to a string, but the reverse is **not** true, getItem makes no attempt to parse it for you. Typescript tries to warn you about the implicit conversion (and the perils thereof) by *requiring* you to *explicitly* pass a converted-to-string value. Generally anything going to/from localStorage should be JSON.stringified/parsed